# Converting a Single Line String to Another Single Line

Tags: java, string

I'm not entirely sure how to convert one string to a completely different string. Specifically, I have to convert

```
System.out.print("Please enter an address formatted as such: 'Apartment or Building Number;Street Address:City:State Postal Code (i.e. NY):Zip Code' ");
```

to

```
System.out.print(
"Apartment or Building Number
Street Address
City, [Postal Code] Zipcode")
```

using the \n operator, all while keeping it a single line. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, as I'm not entirely sure where to start.

Comment: `String#split` will split the incoming text on a common delimiter, for example `:`. This will return an `String` array which you can then use to format as you see fit...

Comment: why `Postal Code (i.e. NY)` not included in the expected output?

Comment: It is, I just changed it to "State" instead of "Postal Code"